Caching using SpatialFocus.MethodCache but with Static Methods in C#
I am trying to use SpatialFocus.MethodCache but with a static method rather than in an instance of a class. I am getting an error:
1>MSBUILD : warning : Fody/SpatialFocus.MethodCache: Class Test contains [Cache] attribute but does not contain a single property implementing IMemoryCache interface
Has anyone had success making this work?
public class Test
{
    static protected IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; }

    [Cache]
    static string Test()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}


Can't confirm or deny if it should or can work but consider "static" to be the new "goto". If you need it its almost always not the right thing to do. I would assume the implementor of the feature you try to use here doesn't even considered it as valid use case and so it will just not work even when maybe possible(or rather easy implementable in the current code).

Is it working correctly for non-static method? If yes, do not use static, consider singleton instead
